# Inserting values of JS-created input textboxes into a database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am using jQuery to create as many input textboxes as the user needs like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#names').on({
    blur: function() {
        var name = $("<p><input class='input' type='text' /></p>")
        var nullFields = 0;
        $(this).closest('div#names').find('input.input').each(function(){
            if($(this).val() == ""){
                nullFields++;
            }
        });
        console.log(nullFields);
        if(nullFields <= 1){
         $('#names').append(name.fadeIn(500));
        }
    }
}, 'input');
 });
</script>
```

Inserting a static textbox into a database isn't a problem using `$_POST['blah']` and`mysql_query("INSERT INTO ...")`, but how do I insert the values of the dynamically created textboxes? I know I'll have to give the textboxes different names as they're created and I presume the MySQL query will be by way of some sort of loop.

**EDIT**

The website in question is [here](http://comfyshoulderrest.com/guestvibe/index.php), specifically at step 4. As mentioned above, step 3 was quite straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example to get you started, not the complete solution.
You create an array for the names then have the php insert each array item

```
var currentArrayNum = 1;    
$('#someClickable').click(function(){

        $('#td').append('<input name="arrayName['+currentArrayNum+']" value="" />');
        currentArrayNum += 1;
    });
```

php:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key){
        if (is_array($key)){
                foreach ($key as $key2 => $value){
                //$key2 will equal arrayName[currentArrayNum]
               //$value will equal the user input for the text field
do some stuff
}
```

Comment: You can just use `name[]` without any index.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. A couple of questions: 1. is there a way to test the javascript? The dynamically created textboxes don't show up in the source code. 2. What exactly is the PHP doing? I don't quite understand what $key is doing...

Comment: When you POST your form to the PHP page that enters into the database the POST is an array. $_POST[key] = value. The dynamically created text fields are now an array inside that array. This script will find the array (is_array) and take each value as $key2 and assign $value. now you can access this inside your foreach loop. might not be the best way for what you are doing but i would need to see how you want to write it to the database.. use print_r($_POST); die(); in your php script to see the array

Answer (score 0):

You can create arrays out of name, simply try this:

```
<input type="text" name="post_input[input_1]" value="">
<input type="text" name="post_input[input_2]" value="">
```

After Submit, you would get an Array out of $_POST["post_input"] with the keys input_1 and input_2 and their assigned values. Then you just loop them as a normal array, for example

```
$aTextFields = $_POST["post_input"];
foreach( $aTextFields as $sValue ) {
  ...
}
```